# wiring audit interceptor to spring context

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, interceptor

I am newbie at Spring so it might be trivial question . but I am working on existing project and trying to add Interceptor following this [post](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/)

**How to wire the Interceptor to the context file ?**

I am getting initialization exception:

```
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [jpaAppContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: 'hibernate.dialect' must be set when no Connection available
```

this is how my context file look like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <!--uncommment below line and make sure you have persistence.xml or use packagestoscan instead-->
        <!--<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="spring-jpa" />-->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.foo.bar.domain"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
                  p:showSql="true"
                  p:generateDdl="false"
                  p:database="MYSQL"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
          p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
          p:driverClassName="@{database.driver}"
          p:url="@{database.url}"
          p:username="@{database.user}"
          p:password="@{database.password}"
          p:maxOpenPreparedStatements="@{database.maxOpenPreparedStatements}"
          p:maxWait="@{database.maxWait}"
          p:poolPreparedStatements="true"/>

    <bean id="transactionManagerWithIsolationSupport" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="placeholderPrefix"  value="@{"/>
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:myApp.default.properties</value>
                <value>file:///opt/bar/config/myApp.local</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    </bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.foo.bar.repository" />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.foo.bar.repository"/>
    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dBPropertiesReader" class="com.foo.util.DBPropertiesReader" init-method="init">
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:mappers/**.xml" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="projectSearchMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
        <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.foo.bar.dao.projectsearch.ProjectSearchMapper" />
        <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="restClient" class="com.foo.util.RestClient" />
</beans>
```

this is how tried to add the Interceptor (without success...) :

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor">
    <property name="entityInterceptor">
        <bean class="com.foo.bar.utils.audit.MyAuditInterceptor"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is my Interceptor:

```
import org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class AccountManagerAuditInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
    public Boolean onSave(Object entity,Serializable id,
                          Object[] state,String[] propertyNames,Type[] types)throws CallbackException {
        System.out.println("onSave");
        return false;
    }
    public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity,Serializable id,
                                Object[] currentState,Object[] previousState,
                                String[] propertyNames,Type[] types)
            throws CallbackException {
        System.out.println("onFlushDirty");
        return false;
    }
    public void onDelete(Object entity, Serializable id,
                         Object[] state, String[] propertyNames,
                         Type[] types) {
        System.out.println("onDelete");

    }
    public void preFlush(Iterator iterator) {
        System.out.println("preFlush");
    }

    public void postFlush(Iterator iterator) {
        System.out.println("postFlush");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is unrelated to the interceptor. Uncomment the line that sets the persistentUnitName property in the entityFactoryBean and verify that persistence.xml is present with the required properties. Here's an example - https://paste.ee/p/j8hkI